How can I connect heavy-gauge wire to a 20A breaker?
I’m replacing an electric stove with a gas stove.  The current 50 amp breaker will need to be replaced with a 20 amp breaker.  My concern is the thicker wire.  Will I need to replace the wiring?
Is it possible to pigtail the proper gauge wire with the existing and, if so, do I need to do it at each end?

I was in a similar situation, but what I did (because I knew what to do and had space in my circuit breaker box and an easy way to run the wiring properly) was to keep the original stove power intact and put in a new 120V circuit dedicated to the gas stove.  That gave me the 120V I needed for the stove, but also in case I (or a future homeowner of this house) ever want to go back to electric, the wiring and plug is all there, ready to go.

As an aside: is there a reason you're going for gas over induction?

Yeah, as much as I like my gas range, the health risks and environmental impact are real.

Why do you need to reduce the breaker? If your wire is correctly sized to 50A, it will serve the gas stove just fine, won't it?

@CarlosMelo A breaker should be the lowest possible value needed for the appliance, otherwise it won't trip until the current becomes far too high

@ThreePhaseEel: Maybe they're putting in other high-power electrical equipment and they won't be able to run both it and an electric stove?

@isherwood: Doesn't an electric stove have more environmental impact than a gas one (because of the extra efficiency-robbing energy-conversion step involved in generating the electricity that'll eventually be used to power the stove)?

@Vikki -- that's a fair point: re load calcs.  however, even with the current state of the grid, induction is going to beat gas on efficiency as well

@DannyBeckett I disagree. The purpose of the breaker isn’t to protect the appliance, it’s to protect the wire/insulation from heating and causing a fire. Their wiring is already properly dimensioned for 50A, there’s no need to replace it.

Thicker wire is always good, usually, except to your wallet.
Breakers/receptacles can usually only fit maybe two gauge sizes larger, so pigtails will be needed at both ends.
20 amp breakers must have the minimum of 12 gauge wire in the total circuit, so 12, 10, maybe 8(if fits) gauge wire can be use for the pigtails with the proper size of wire nuts/lever type connectors.

"except to your wallet" - and OP doesn't even have to worry about that disadvantage, since the wires in question're already installed and paid for.

You need to pigtail it at each end.  Don't damage or shorten the existing wire and don't throw out the breaker.  It's an asset if you or a future occupant want to go back to electric.
In the panel, if the wires are very short (sometimes people enter the panel right next to the breaker and cut them just right) .... you should remove the cable from the panel and install a junction box nearby to do the splice.
At the stove end you may need to replace the box.  Look at its location, and assuming your new range has a plug, imagine a plug sticking out, look at the recess in the new range to make sure it will all fit. If not, or if the box is too small for both the splice and the new outlet, you'll need to find the right combination of bigger or multiple or relocated boxes to suit the situation.

Stove end probably depends on how the existing stove is connected—cable could be connected directly to the stove, could be a whip from the stove to a J-box, could be a plugged cord from the stove to an outlet box.

There might be a problem with the breaker, there might not. It depends on the wire and the breaker. For example, the Eaton CHF120 can connect to up to 8 AWG wires. 8 AWG copper in a cable is only enough for 40A and 8 AWG aluminum 40A, but 8 AWG copper THWN (or similar) is good for up to 50A. So there is a possibility, depending on the cable/wire type and depending on the breaker type, that you can connect the wire directly to the breaker.
The problem will be on the other end. In a quick search I haven't found anything that takes any wires larger than 10 AWG. So pigtailing will almost certainly be needed for the receptacle end.
There is also one other very serious possibility to look for:

Original 40A circuit with 50A receptacle. This is allowed as there is no 40A receptacle. This could be with 8 AWG copper cable or wires or 8 AWG aluminum.
40A breaker replaced with 50A breaker either because new stove needed 50A or due to nuisance tripping, and in both cases replacing the breaker without upgrading the cable/wires would not be a good (or code compliant) idea.

In that situation you might have 8 AWG copper cable that is only rated for up to 40A. Which is fine for 20A, but which means if you wanted to switch back to a larger circuit then 40A would be the limit.

Yes, you will need a splice on both ends, since the wire is probably too large for both the 20A circuit breaker and the receptacle.
Splicing heavy gauge wires can be substantially harder than pigtailing a few 12 gauge wires together, and if the existing stove wire is aluminum, you have to use a splicing method specifically designed for bonding copper and aluminum.
Polaris connectors solve both of these problems. They are insulated connectors with ports that accept copper or aluminum wires of a wide range of sizes, and splice them together. They're substantially more expensive than wire nuts, but they're really easy to use, and this is a great use for them.
A few other companies make a similar product, and I have no recommendation for one brand over the other. Polaris is just the de facto trade name, kind of like Romex or Kleenex.

As an alternative option, there do exist adapters that can convert a NEMA 14-50 receptacle into a 5-15. Here's an example from the orange store. The critically important bit is that your existing receptacle has neutral/ground properly wired, and that the adapter has within it some kind of fuse that will pop at 15A (this example does) since the existing breaker won't.
Might be worth considering, especially if you don't want to have to undo this work later to go back to electric/induction/dual-fuel.

Hi all and thx for your experience, insights and reflections.
Starters:  I selected gas over electric as I own a rental property which I now live in.  3 units in the building so 3 ranges.  Over the years tenants have ruined the two electric cooktops by pure neglect and bad cleaning decisions, whereas the gas range is functioning perfectly.
The specific problem with the tenants and electric is they create a burn build up around each of the burners.  It just leads them down the path of sampling cleaning products - none work, btw.
(The solution is simple - carefully use a blade to remove the buildup).
I’m in Chicago and the city has a directive for electric for all new construction - so a nod to those who advocate for electric.  I’m in a graystone built 100 years ago so m not subject to the ordinance.
In the end, I hired an electrician.  He pulled the thick wire and ran 12 gauge in all of 5 minutes as the panel is 15 feet from receptacle and it is a dedicated circuit running up wall/across ceiling/down wall.  I insisted he take the thick wiring for a future job so it does get an extended life.
Thanks all!

I've done this exact project (converted from electric to gas) and I found that the #8 AWG wire for the old 40 amp circuit still fit into the 20 amp circuit breaker that I bought, and in the 20 amp receptacle on the other end.  Your mileage may vary.  So try it before you assume you need to splice.  If it doesn't fit, then as others here are saying, it's perfectly fine to use appropriately sized wire nuts (NOT WAGOS) to attach #12 AWG pigtails to the existing wires to extend into the breaker and receptacle terminals.

40A is much more common. But OP stated they have a 50A breaker. That could be 8 AWG (correctly with copper wire, incorrectly with aluminum wire or copper cable) or it could be 6 AWG. 6 AWG will probably fit on some breakers but not others and is very unlikely to fit on receptacles.
